# The Chinese car deal

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, story

> Me and my darling were in China recently and decided to buy a brand new car from a trustworthy-looking local fellow. Afterwards, I noticed some similarities between
>
> 1. My darling,
> 2. the language we used,
> 3. our new car's colour, and
> 4. the car itself.

Do you think we are happy with our new car?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All four of those could be different types of

> Citrus:
>  My darling is *[Clementine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Darling_Clementine)*
>  The language is *[Mandarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandarin_Chinese)*
>  The car was *[Lime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lime_(color))* or *[Orange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_(colour))* colored
>  The car turned out to be a *[Lemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemon_(automobile))*
>  That means, in the end, you weren't happy with your new car.

Comment: He was left feeling rot 13(fbhe) :P

Comment: I had another colour in mind, but this works perfectly.

Comment: That colour doesn't begin with T, does it? @jafe

Comment: @Nij Begins with O ;)

Comment: @jafe 'tis an Rot13(benatr), I bet :P